# Inserting values into nested tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm fairly new to Lua, and programming in general. I've been wondering how to use `table.insert` for nested tables. So far this is what I've written, but it does not insert anything into the nested tables.

```
days = {d1 = {},d2 = {},d3 = {},d4 = {},d5 = {},d6 = {},d7 = {},d8 = {},d9 ={},d10 = {},d11 = {},d12 = {},d13 = {},d14 = {},d15 = {},d16 = {},d17 = {},d18 =  {},d19 = {},d20 = {},d21 = {},d22 = {},d23 = {},d24 = {},d25 = {} , d26 = {}, d27 = {}, d28 = {}, d29 = {}, d30 = {}, d31 = {}}
dw = 0
dh = 0
for _,v in pairs(days) do
    for _,v in pairs(v) do
        table.insert(v, dw)
        table.insert(v, dh)
    end
end

for _,v in pairs(days) do
    for _,v in pairs(v) do
        print(v)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through a table to add values to it. In fact, adding values to a table as you're iterating on it *might* cause the loop to never exit, as it adds new values *every* iteration. Luckily, your tables are empty so the program never enters that loop.

```
for _,v in pairs(days) do
    for _,v in pairs(v) do -- <- unnecessary, potentially dangerous!
        table.insert(v, dw)
        table.insert(v, dh)
    end
end
```

Simply remove the inner loop.

```
for _,v in pairs(days) do
    table.insert(v, dw)
    table.insert(v, dh)
end
```

Also, consider other options of generating this set of tables.

```
local days = (function (t)
    for n = 1, 31 do
        t['d' .. n] = { 0, 0 }
    end

    return t
end) {}
```

Simplified:

```
local days = {}

for n = 1, 31 do
    days['d' .. n] = { 0, 0 }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for that Oka. That really helps. Can someone explain how "function (t)" works how  "t['d' ..n]" works and why theres "return t".

Comment: @laquishabonquiquithe3rd `t['d' .. n]` is a concatenation of the string `'d'` with the current index of the loop, creating `'d1', 'd2', 'd3'`, and so on, for use as keys in the table `t`. `t` is the first argument to the function, which is passed in as a new empty table after the function expression (`{}`). We return `t` so it's assigned to the `days` variable. This was a bit of an advanced hint that you should consider wrapping this logic up in a function, especially if you are going to create multiple of these tables. Simply extract that function, give it a name, and replace the expression.